# How do I stop JavaScript from parsing until React render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Not sure if that's even the right question to be asking, but it got you to click :)

The issue is that most of my text's translation isn't updating when the i18n global language updates.  In this example, looking at the rendering of {this.state.topNav}. *The link that I added above the render of that state object translates*, but the array passed through state doesn't translate when the user changes the global language (it will render the correct initial translation though).

I titled the question as above because it seems like the issue might be that the map function in the function.js code is causing the issue, because the translating is being done there instead of when rendering.  I tried moving the map function into render, but this causes an infinite rendering loop.

```
.....

class TopNav extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      topNav:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    const data = getData(i18n.language, 'header');
    data.then((json) => {
      var nav = navLinks(json, 'row1', t);
      this.setState({topNav:nav});
    });

    this.handleLanguageChange = this.handleLanguageChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleLanguageChange(event) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    return(
      <header>
        <nav>
          <a>{t('row1.button1.label')}</a>
            {this.state.topNav}
        </nav>
        <select onChange={this.handleLanguageChange}>
          <option value='en'>English</option>
          <option value='es'>Spanish</option>
        </select>
      </header>

    )
  }
}

export default withTranslation('header')(TopNav);
```

functions.js (excerpt)

```
export function navLinks(json, key, t) {
  const items = mkNumArray(json, key);
  return (
    items.map( (i) => {
      const url = t(key + ".button" + i + ".url");
      const label = t(key + ".button" + i + ".label");
      return (
        <a href={url} key={i}>{label}</a>
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: in `handleLanguageChange`, do you mean to write `this.props.i18n` instead of `i18n`?

Comment: so `i18n` is an object  with a `changeLanguage` method? you might considering adding that code to the question.

Comment: Put data in state, not react elements. `navLinks` should only return data

Comment: there is a line importing i18n, it's the standard import and setup from react i18next, so I don't think it's necessary to include

Comment: ok @AndyRay, thinking about that

Comment: Yep @AndyRay, that was the move! I'm not going to post my updated code, but basically I separated out the two parts of that function and stored the index array in state during componentDidMount() and then created the actual elements in render()

Answer (score 0):

OK I did add some code here (full file), credit to @andy-ray for the helpful comment above.

```
import React from "react";

import {Container,Row,Col} from '../imports';
import {getData, newNavLinks, mkNumArray} from '../functions';

import { useTranslation, withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import i18n from '../i18n';

import logo from '../assets/emerson-logo.png';

class TopNav extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      topNav:[],
      secNav:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    const data = getData(i18n.language, 'header');
    data.then((json) => {
      var nav = mkNumArray(json, 'row1');
      var secNav = mkNumArray(json,'row2')
      this.setState({topNav:nav, secNav: secNav});
    });

    this.handleLanguageChange = this.handleLanguageChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleLanguageChange(event) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    const topNav = newNavLinks('row1', this.state.topNav, t);
    const secNav = newNavLinks('row2', this.state.secNav, t);

    return(
      <header>

        <nav id='main-header' className='row' >
          <Container>
            <Row className='bg-dark text-light'>
              <Col xs={10}>
                <div className='links justify-content-center d-flex'>
                <a>{t('row1.button1.label')}</a>
                  {topNav}
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col className='text-center px-4' xs={2}>
                <div id='global-language-select'>
                  <select onChange={this.handleLanguageChange}>
                    <option value='en'>English</option>
                    <option value='es'>Spanish</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col className='col-3'>
                <a href={t('row2.button0.url')}><img src={logo} alt={t("row2.button0.label")}/></a>
              </Col>
              <Col className='d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center links'>
                {secNav}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </nav>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

export default withTranslation('header')(TopNav);
```

functions.js

```
export function mkNumArray(object,path) {
  //if (n.isArray()) {
  var n = arrCount(object,path);
  var foo = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     foo.push(i);
  }

  return foo;
}

export function mkArray(n) {
  //if (n.isArray()) {
  if ( Array.isArray(n)) {
    n = n.length;
  }
  var foo = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     foo.push(i);
  }
  return foo;
}

export const getData = (lng, ns) => {
  var jsonRequest = fetch('/locales/' + lng + '/' + ns + '.json', {
      headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((jsonData) => {
    return jsonData;
  });
  return jsonRequest;
}

export function arrayify(initObject, path) {
  var object = initObject[path];
  const arr = [];
  var menuKeys = Object.keys( object );

  menuKeys.forEach( (element, index) => {
      arr[element] = object[element];
  });

  return arr;
}

export function arrCount(object, path) {
  return Object.keys(arrayify(object,path)).length;
}

export function navLinks(json, key, t) {
  const items = mkNumArray(json, key);
  return (
    items.map( (i) => {
      const url = t(key + ".button" + i + ".url");
      const label = t(key + ".button" + i + ".label");
      return (
        <a href={url} key={i}>{label}</a>
      );
    })
  );
}

export function newNavLinks(key, arr, t) {
  return (
    arr.map( (i) => {
      const url = t(key + ".button" + i + ".url");
      const label = t(key + ".button" + i + ".label");
      return (
        <a href={url} key={i}>{label}</a>
      );
    })
  );
}
```